# Skip running PITest in maven build

Tags: java, maven, pitest

I'm trying to run a maven build from command line and exclude PITest from running any mutations. Currently the reports are failing and we need to be able to give a parameter to ignore running the mutation tests or ignore the results and continue the build

I've running with some parameters like `mvn package -Dpit.report=true`

or `mvn package -Dmaven.report.skip=true`

This is the PITest setup in my pom

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
    <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.10</version>
    <configuration>
        <timestampedReports>false</timestampedReports>
        <mutationThreshold>95</mutationThreshold>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>mutationCoverage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The problem is that is is still running PITest and causing the build to fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native way of skipping a plugin execution, but there are least 2 workarounds:

- First, is adding a property to override execution **phase**:

Define a property `pitPhase` with default value as the default phase of plugin execution.

Then in plugin configuration:

```
<execution>
   <phase>${pitPhase}</phase>
   ...
</execution>
```

After that, when you want to skip execution `mvn -DskipPit=pitPhase package`

- The other alternative is to add a [Maven profile](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) with the plugin execution

Answer (score 4):

Since 1.4.11 there is the option `skipPitest`.  See here: https://github.com/hcoles/pitest/releases/tag/pitest-parent-1.4.11

So you do: `-DskipPitest`

Answer (score 1):

The execution of Pitests can be skipped in Maven.

In your pom.xml:

1. Set in general properties:

```
<properties> 
       <pitest.execution.skip>true</pitest.execution.skip> 
</properties>
```

2. Set in the plugin:

```
 <plugin>
         <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
         <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
         <version>Your_Version</version>
         <configuration>
            <skip>${pitest.execution.skip}</skip>
         </configuration>
 </plugin>
```